# ViewPager and animating content of default fragment

Tags: android, animation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I try to animate the content(textViews etc) of fragments, which are attached to ViewPager, animation  works nice when we move from fragment to fragment. I need also animate the fragment which is seen when app is lunched and problems comes, here is my code of method connected with support fragments

```
private void initializeFrags() {
    List<Fragment>  ourlist = new Vector<Fragment>();
    ourlist.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FirstFrag.class.getName()));
    ourlist.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, SecondFrag.class.getName()));
    ourlist.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, ThirdFrag.class.getName()));
    adapter = new ouradapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), ourlist);
    ourPlace = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.mypager);
    ourPlace.setAdapter(adapter);

    // this method generates the errrors
    firstAnimation();

    ourPlace.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
            if(arg0==0)
            {
                View v = adapter.getItem(arg0).getView();
                TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstText);
                 Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
                text.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
            }

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Integer.toString(arg0), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

I try to add here the method `firstanimation`, which animates content of `firstfragment`, the `initializeFrags()` is lunched during `onCreate` so it would be executed only when app is lunched.

Here is code of `firstanimation` method:

```
private void firstAnimation()
{
    View v = adapter.getItem(0).getView();
    TextView text = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstText);
    Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.fade);
    text.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
}
```

and I got the error,

```
12-08 21:45:33.102: E/Trace(29275): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.worry.fragmentwithanimation/com.worry.fragmentwithanimation.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2062)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:133)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1198)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.worry.fragmentwithanimation.MainActivity.firstAnimation(MainActivity.java:88)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.worry.fragmentwithanimation.MainActivity.initializeFrags(MainActivity.java:51)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at com.worry.fragmentwithanimation.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:34)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2026)
12-08 21:45:33.333: E/AndroidRuntime(29275):    ... 11 more
```

I try also animate it in fragment:

```
TextView first;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container,false);
    first=(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.firstText);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if(isVisibleToUser)
    {


         Animation fadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.fade);
         first.startAnimation(fadeInAnimation );
    }
}
```

and I got this error

```
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at com.worry.fragmentwithanimation.FirstFrag.setUserVisibleHint(FirstFrag.java:34)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:130)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1066)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:622)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:404)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:855)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:578)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4950)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:314)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2154)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15401)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1856)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1279)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1002)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4294)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:643)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4803)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
12-08 23:05:38.541: E/AndroidRuntime(31143):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm asking how can I solve this problem to animate also the fragment which is shown when activity is started. I googled some time but in other question I can see only the animation when we change one fragment to other and this issue is handled by the onPageSelected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong in the fragment animation attempt :

```
TextView first;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.first, container,false);
    first=(TextView) view.findById(R.id.firstText);
    return view;
}
```

The other attempt has no chance to work right as you fragment may not (and actually is not) created when your activity is created. It will happen later thus first is null when you try to animate it.

Comment: Why don't you try to start animation in onActivityCreated ?

Comment: thx a lot, yeah it works perfectly, thx a lot;) but for me it was visible for user (setUserVisibleHint) == created (onActivityCreated), it's only shows, how my knowledge is incomplete xD I mark this answer cause your comment solve this problem